# ¿Existen paquetes de idioma para Netbeans 11?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy trabajando con Netbeans 11.1 pero no encuentro paquetes de idioma para configurarlo en español.

¿Solo está disponible en inglés?
Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que elimines la pregunta. Ve a [ask] para mas informacion. Te darás cuenta que carece de calidad. Aun así es bueno responder respecto a tu pregunta a modo de comentario: Por lo que tengo entendido no existe un instalador oficial. Al parecer solo hay binarios y como ni siquiera se le acerca a la version LTS no esperes que uno de los features sean los idiomas. Asi que si no puedes cambiar con el archivo `netbeans.conf` cambiando el idioma en la linea: `netbeans_default_options="-J-Duser.language=en-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-X`, entonces no contiene los archivos de idioma

Comment: En la versión 11 sí que hay instalador y es versión LTS

Comment: Puedes subir el enlace del instalador para comprobarlo?... Solo encuentro binarios

Comment: https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html